# Golang: chaining function to returnself

Tags: function, go, types, casting, wrapper

This Code doesn't work as type amount isn't int, I want to know why go doesnt know how to handle this custom type? 
I know  that
    `var x amount = 8` will fix this function because it wants a amount but my teacher insists that both these functions are 100% equivalent, to my eyes they are not because of the aforementioned error in type.

I am hoping someone can help me with this.

```
type amount int
func main() {

    x := 8
    y := foo(x)
    fmt.Println(y)
}

func foo(x amount) amount {
    return x * x
}
```

This code does work which seems to be the same sort of composition.

```
func Auth1(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
        fmt.Println("here is the authorization code")
        c := mcookie.GetCookie(req)
        cl := db[c.Value]
        if !cl.Loggedin {
            http.Redirect(w, req, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        }
        h(w, req)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function foo() is expecting an **amount** type as parameter, all you have to do is is pass **x** as amount, like this: `y := foo(amount(x))`

working example: https://play.golang.org/p/xkbp43vjyA

In Go the type is very important, for example if you are creating a type **amount** is because you may want add more behavior than an **int** defining methods, so if your function is receiving an **amount** you have to pass that type no matter if it's compatible with int or not.

Comment: I know this, I added this too fix the function,    var x amount = 8

Comment: So, important rule to understand about number constants like `8`.  They have no type at all when on their own, and the compiler will coerce them into any type actually capable of holding a number.  However, as soon as they are assigned to a variable, that _variable_ has a concrete and unchangeable type, and must be explicitly converted to any other concrete (non-interface) type.  The shortform assignment `x := 8` is equivalent to `var x = 8`, with the type elided and left to the compiler to decide.  In the absence of a type, integer values default to type `int`.

Comment: This can have impact in `for` loops, by the way.  The form `for x := 0; x < y; x++` sets `x` as an `int` type.  If you needed `x` to be an `amount` like in your code, you would need to explicitly cast the integer constant: `for x := amount(0); x < y; x++`

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, it is as I suspected.